# How is this checkmate? I’m new to chess

Tags: rules, checkmate

I’m new to chess.
How is this checkmate?

```
[FEN ""]
[Date "Dec 31 2019"]
[White "User 21050 (Lvl 3 500pts)"]
[Black "Computer (Level 20 3000+pts)"]

1.Nf3 a5 2.Ng5 h5 3.Nxf7 g6 4.Nxh8 g5 5.Ng6 Ra6 6.Ne5 Bh6 7.Nf3 c6 8.Nxg5 c5 9.Nf3 Qc7 10.e3 Rg6 11.Bd3 Bg5 12.Bxg6+ Kd8 13.Bxh5 d5 14.Nxg5 Qc6 15.O-O b6 16.d3 Qb7 17.Bd2 Bf5 18.e4 Qd7 19.exf5 e6 20.fxe6 d4 21.Qe2 b5 22.Qe4 a4 23.Qxd4 Qd6 24.Qxc5 Qf8 25.Qxb5 Qe8 26.Qxa4 Qe7 27.Qb4 Qa7 28.Qa4 Na6 29.Qxa6 Ne7 30.Qxa7 Ng6 31.Qg7 Nh8 32.Qxh8+ Ke7 33.Qh6 Kd8 34.e7+ Kc7 35.e8=B Kb8 36.Bb5 Ka8 37.d4 Kb7 38.d5 Kb8 39.d6 Kb7 40.d7 Kc7 41.d8=B+ Kb8 42.Bf6 Kb7 43.Bd4 Kb8 44.Ba4 Kc7 45.c4 Kb7 46.B4e3 Kc7 47.Bb5 Kc8 48.Bc6 Kc7 49.Bd5 Kb8 50.Be4 Kc7 51.Bc2 Kd7 52.Be2 Kc8 53.Ba7 Kd8 54.Bb6+ Kc8 55.Bc7 Kd7 56.Bd6 Kc6 57.Bc5+ Kd7 58.Bd6 Kd8 59.Be7+ Kc8 60.Bd8 Kxd8 61.a4 Ke8 62.c5 Kd7 63.Bf5+ Kd8 64.Bd7 Kxd7 65.c6+ Ke7 66.c7 Ke8 67.c8=B Ke7 68.Bf5 Kd8 69.Bc2 Kc7 70.b4 Kc8 71.a5 Kd7 72.b5 Kc7 73.a6 Kb8 74.a7+ Kc8 75.a8=B Kc7 76.Bc6 Kd8 77.Bd5 Ke7 78.Ba2 Kd8 79.b6 Ke7 80.b7 Kd8 81.b8=B Ke7 82.Be5 Kd8 83.Bb2 Kd7 84.f4 Ke8 85.f5 Kd7 86.f6 Kc6 87.f7+ Kd7 88.f8=B Ke8 89.Bc5 Kd8 90.Bf2 Kc7 91.g4 Kd8 92.h4 Ke8 93.Ne6 Kd7 94.Nf4 Kc8 95.Ne6 Kb8 96.Nc7 Kxc7 97.g5 Kb7 98.g6 Kc7 99.g7 Kd8 100.g8=B Kc8 101.Bgd5 Kb8 102.Bg2 Kc8 103.Qg6 Kb8 104.h5 Kc7 105.h6 Kc8 106.h7 Kd8 107.h8=B Kd7 108.Bhe5 Ke7 109.Bh2 Kd8 110.Bfg3 Kd7 111.Rf7+ Kc8 112.Rf8+ Kd7 113.Rf6 Ke7 114.Re6+ Kd8 115.Qg4 Kc8 116.Re7+ Kd8 117.Re8+ Kxe8 118.Nc3 Kd8 119.Nd5 Ke8 120.Ne7 Kd8 121.Nc8 Ke8 122.Ne7 Kf8 123.Ng6+ Ke8 124.Nf8 Kd8 125.Nd7 Ke7 126.Nf6 Kf8 127.Rf1 Ke7 128.Rf5 Kd8 129.Re5 Kc7 130.Re8+ Kb6 131.Rb8+ Ka7 132.Ra8+ Kb6 133.Rc8 Ka7 134.Bh4 Kb6 135.Bhf4 Ka7 136.Bfg5 Kb6 137.Rc7 Kxc7 138.Nd7 Kd6 139.Nf6 Ke7 140.Ne8+ Kf8 141.Ba1 Kxe8 142.Bcb1 Kf8 143.Bc1 Ke8 144.Bd1 Kf8 145.Bcb2 Ke8 146.Bdc2 Kf8 147.Be1 Ke8 148.Bgc1 Kf8 149.Bed2 Ke7 150.Bf1 Kf8 151.Be2 Ke7 152.Bed1 Ke8 153.Qg8+ Kd7 154.Qd8+ Kxd8 155.Be2 Kd7 156.Bdc3 Ke8 157.Be3 Kd8 158.Bcd2 Kc7 159.Bcb3 Kc8 160.Bbd3 Kd7 161.Bbc2 Kc8 162.Ba3 Kd7 163.Bad4 Kc8 164.Bab2 Kc7 165.Bf2 Kd8 166.Be4 Ke7 167.Bg2 Kd8 168.Bde3 Ke8 169.Bf4 Kf8 170.Bh2 Ke7 171.Kf1 Kd8 172.Ke1 Ke8 173.Kd1 Kd8 174.Bhg3 Kd7 175.Bh3+ Kd8 176.Bf3 Ke8 177.Bfe3 Kd8 178.Bdc3 Ke8 179.Bd3 Kd8 180.Ba3 Ke8 181.Bb3 Kd8 182.Ba7 Ke8 183.Ba6 Kd8 184.Ba5+ Ke8 185.Ba4+ Kf7 186.Ke2 Kg8 187.Kd3 Kg7 188.Bgf2 Kg6 189.Bf1 Kh6 190.B3e2 Kh7 191.Bed1 Kg8 192.Bdb3+ Kh8 193.Bfe1 Kg7 194.Bec3+ Kh6 195.Be2 Kh7 196.Bed1 Kh6 197.Bdc2 Kh5 198.Ba2 Kg4 199.Ba1 Kg3 200.Kd4 Kf3 201.Be4+ Kg4 202.Ba8 Kg3 203.B6b7 Kf4 204.Bac6 Kg3 205.Bad5 Kg4 206.Kd3 Kh5 207.Bf3+ Kg5 208.Be3+ Kh4 209.Bg2 Kh5 210.Bf2 Kg5 211.Bad4 Kh5 212.Bgf3+ Kg6 213.Bce4+ Kf7 214.Bbd5+ Ke8 215.Bac6#
```

Comment: You might get better answers for the difficulty your having if you explain why you don't think it's checkmate.

Comment: If that's Level 20 3000+ points, I'd hate to see level 1.

Answer (score 7):

Actually this looks like a draw by the 50 move rule.

FIDE

### 9.3 The game is drawn, upon a correct claim by the player having the move, if:

> b. the last 50 consecutive moves have been made by each player without
>   the movement of any pawn and without any capture.

Comment: No, the https://chess.com iPad app notified me of checkmate.

Comment: Doesn't the player have to CLAIM the draw and an arbiter confirm it before the 50 move rule or third repetition  case is established making it a draw?

Comment: Yes, yobamamama.

Comment: 75 moves is automatic draw, though.

Comment: since user20105 said they were using chess.com app I played a game against myself with the chess.com app.  I find that the app automatically draws the game on 3 fold repetition or 50 move rule.  I wonder why that didn't happen in the game in question.

Answer (score 6):

After white's move `215. Bac6#`, the black king is now in check and all of the black's possible moves (`d8`, `f8`, `d7`, `e7`, `f7`) are illegal since they result in check.

The result is checkmate.

Answer (score 5):

Black is in check.  The black king has no moves to get out of check as all other squares it can move to are covered.  Black has no other pieces to use to stop the check with.

Admittedly I only looked at the end position and did not wade through all the moves to see if a draw could have occurred earlier.